# what events are bound?

Tags: jquery, events

Is there any way to see what events are bound to an element with jQuery?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you are using Safari or Chrome, you can open up the `Developer Tools` and inspect the element (by clicking the magnifying glass). In the `Event Listeners` tab on the right it will tell you the binded events to that element, with their functions and locations.

OR to do this via code:

```
$('selector').data('events'); // get
console.dir($('selector').data('events')); // display in firefox firebug or webkit's developer tools
```

Comment: I've updated my question to include a code example to see the attached events.

Comment: The developer tools from Chrome does it display the events binded with jQuery?

Comment: Yep. Here is a screenshot:
http://img830.imageshack.us/img830/1372/tmpu.png

I've also included in my answer how to fetch the listeners using javascript, so you don't need to use a browser console.

Comment: @Adrian - Make sure to accept this as the answer if it answered your question via the checkmark on the left :)

Comment: This just isn't working for me.  I'm only getting undefined returned when I call .data('events') on elements that clearly have events assigned to them.  Any idea what could be wrong??

Comment: Ryan ask it in a new question and attach a link here :)

Answer (score 8):

This solution is obsolete in new jQuery versions. You must use:

```
 $._data($('selector')[0],'events')
```

Comment: That is obsolete too now. Use `$._data($('selector'),'events')`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need this in script, you can check that element in any DOM inspection tool like Firebug and see all events.

Comment: with Firebug can you also see what events are bound with jQuery?

Comment: Yes, and with anything other. Also you can do the same with Chrome/Safari/Opera Developer Tools.

Comment: I must be blind but I can't find the Event Listener tab in Firebug. I use Firebug 1.5.4 and Firequery.

Comment: Then you can check this discussion - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570960/how-to-debug-javascript-jquery-event-bindings-with-firebug-or-similar-tool

Comment: it seems that the Events Panel is added from Firefox 3.7a1pre not in Firefox 3.6.*