# Checking if custom event is set

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

```
$('#element').bind({
    specialEvent : function()
    {
        console.log(1);
    }
});
```

How do I check whether the element has the `specialEvent` event or not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288222/what-events-are-bound

Comment: $('#element').data('events') === undefined

Comment: sorry but I didn't know you are using jQuery 1.8 - it was a change in this version (see the answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery 1.8 `$(element).data('events')` has been removed, but you can still get to the events data for debugging purposes via `$._data(element, "events")` - check [this](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/).

```
console.log($._data(element, 'events'));
```

Comment: try provide only the raw element id: $._data(element_id_without_quotes_nor_sharp, 'events'); http://jsfiddle.net/DHmVZ/1/

Comment: yep... for me too, I don't know if this is a bug or what